# "Moving" a value from one row to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to MySQL and I really don't know how to google this. Sorry if it's a dumb question.

I have a table that contains unique value pairs as the primary key (userID, somethingID) and a value. For example,

```
userID     somethingID    value
892        10             1
892        9              1
892        0              10
```

If (userID, **somethingID = 0**) has a value greater than 0, the user should be able to decrement that value and increment the value of any other row. In the example above, userID 892 has a value of 10 in somethingID 0, so if he wants, he could take 1 from that value and move it to (892, 9):

```
userID     somethingID    value
892        10             1
892        9              2
892        0              9
```

I need to add a check that ensures the value row of (userID, 0) is greater than zero before doing so. The value of (userID, 0) cannot be negative.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: You could have done with update query , but there is an issue. When you write anquery for ex (Select * from table where somethingID = 0 ) . You cannot guarantee the order in which they result may return, i.e there is no positional reference to each row. You need need an order by clause to identify the predecessor row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to write a procedure for this job, because you need to update multiple lines.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateValue(
    IN  _userID INT,  
    IN  _somethingID  INT  
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tableName SET value = value +1 where userID=_userID and somethingID= _somethingID  and userID in (
          select userID from tableName where userID=_userID and somethingID= 0 and value >0
        );
    UPDATE tableName SET value = value -1 where userID=_userID and somethingID= 0  and userID in (
          select userID from tableName where userID=_userID and somethingID= 0 and value >0
        );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can call this procedure with desired User Id and and Something ID values.

```
CALL UpdateValue(892,9);
```

If you need additional information about modified lines then you can add an OUT variable to procedure and return desired values. I hope this helps for you as an starting point for further searches.

Comment: Thank you! I need to send the request from C#. I think it can be done since I'm already doing the "take one from here, add it there", just didn't know how to do the validation. I'll do my research. You've been very helpful, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select userid,
  max(case when somethingid > 0 then somethingid end) somethingid,
  max(case when somethingid = 0 and value > 0 then value end) zero_value
from tablename  
group by userid
having zero_value is not null;
```

returns the `userid`s that contain rows with `somethingid = 0` and `value > 0` and a `somethingid > 0`.
 
You can join it to the table in the update statement:

```
update tablename t
inner join (
  select userid,
    max(case when somethingid > 0 then somethingid end) somethingid,
    max(case when somethingid = 0 and value > 0 then value end) zero_value
  from tablename  
  group by userid
  having zero_value is not null
) g on g.userid = t.userid 
    and ((t.somethingid = 0 and t.value = g.zero_value)  or (t.somethingid = g.somethingid))  
set t.value = case 
  when t.somethingid = g.somethingid then t.value + 1
  else t.value - 1
end;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Ke48XQz7XtrM9ibK7UTKM/0).